# how add custom validator for `javax.validation.constraints` annotation?

Tags: java, bean-validation, spring-validator

I have implemented validation for `Long` field and `@PastOrPresent` validation

```
public class PastOrPresentValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PastOrPresent, Long>{
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Long value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return value <= System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

public class MyDto {
    @PastOrPresent
    Long timestamp;    
}
```

And got error:

```
HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.PastOrPresent' validating type 'java.lang.Long'. Check configuration for 'push.dto.timestamp'
```

But when I create custom annotation like `@PastOrPresentLong` and use same validator code everything works.

Is there a way to add custom validator for `javax.validation.constraints` annotation?

Comment: I think you should accept this wonderful answer.

Answer (score 7):

Just implementing the `ConstraintValidator` interface isn't enough for your new validator to work. It should be somehow registered so that BeanValidation provider knows about it. This can be done via XML (see for more info [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-constraints-car)):

```
<constraint-mappings
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping/validation-mapping-2.0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <!-- anything else -->
    <constraint-definition annotation="javax.validation.constraints.PastOrPresent">
        <validated-by include-existing-validators="true">
            <value>org.mycompany.PastOrPresentLongValidator</value>
        </validated-by>
    </constraint-definition>
</constraint-mappings>
```

Then if you are using Hibernate Validator as BeanValidation provider you also have two more options - use service loader or programmatic definition.
Using Service loader is the easiest way of adding new validator. All you need to do is create a `META-INF/services/javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` file and add a FQCN of your validator to it. See detailed examples in this [post](http://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/) under section "Use standard constraints for non standard classes" or in the [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_constraint_definitions_via_code_serviceloader_code).
With [programmatic approach](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-constraint-definition) you would have to do something like:

```
ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
        .constraintDefinition( PastOrPresent.class )
        .validatedBy( PastOrPresentLongValidator.class );
```

And then add this constraint mapping to your configuration and create a validator from it:

```
Validator validator = configuration.addMapping( constraintMapping )
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```

But as I mentioned earlier - Service Loader is the easiest and quickest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

### Simpler Approach

A simpler declarative approach to linking the annotation to the validator is to specify the linkage through a Constraint(validatedBy) annotation.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = PastOrPrsentValidator.class)
public class PastOrPresentValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PastOrPresent, Long>{
...
```

Comment: I think he is trying to create a custom validator for an existing `@Constraint`, not write a new one. This might be the simpler solution, though, since the registration can occur automagically.